# How can I connect to an AWS MSSQL database over an SSH tunnel, using node.js?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-rds

i’m trying to connect to a remote database that only allows connections through an ssh tunnel using node.js.

i’m scratching my head how to set this up using [tunnel-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2) and [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) together, particularly what the source and destination ports should be. i’ve got something like this right now:

```
require("dotenv").config()

const sql = require("mssql")
const tunnel = require("tunnel-ssh")

const tnl = tunnel(
  {
    host: process.env.SSH_HOST,
    port: process.env.SSH_PORT,
    username: process.env.SSH_USER,
    privateKey: require("fs").readFileSync(process.env.SSH_KEYFILE_PATH),

    // more needed here?
  },
  (error, tnl) => {
    if (error) console.log(error)
    const db = mssql
    .connect(
      `mssql://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@${process.env.DB_HOST}/${process.env.DB_NAME}`
    )
    .then(() => {
      const result = mssql.query`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
      console.log(result)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
)
```

at the moment `tunnel-ssh` is complaining with `ConfigError: dstPort` not set, but i’m not sure what the source and destination ports should actually be?

i've also tried using `ssh2` instead of `tunnel-ssh`.

i want my ssh connection on the normal port (22) and my database is listening for connections on port 1433.

how does this map onto source and destinations?

---

**UPDATE:** aha! i've managed to get this working using the command line ssh client.

a bit more info: i'm connecting to an aws rds instance through a bastion jump box.

now, i only vaguely understand what those words mean, but i've managed to get an ssh tunnel working using a command like this:

```
ssh -f -N -L 1433:my-db.1234566.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:1433 ec2-user@bastion.ec2.ip.here -v
```

**how might i convert this command into the format that tunnel-ssh expects?**

Comment: Why don't you create it with `ssh` on your SO instead of using node?

Comment: so = os? i'm going to do other stuff after i connect lol - this is gonna be the basis of a web app eventually

Comment: Yes, OS. The tunnel can be there for the entire session (as in, as long as the OS is being used).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the nature of the SSH tunnel. The point of it is to map a port on your system to a remote port on another system. So any connections done on the local port will be forwarded to the destination port on the remote server.

Here are [example configurations](https://github.com/agebrock/tunnel-ssh#config-example) for it on their repository.

> i want my ssh connection on the normal port (22) and my database is
> listening for connections on port 1433.

Well, you can...

```
    var config = {
      username:'root',
      password:'secret',
      host:sshServer,
      port:22,
      dstHost:destinationServer,
      dstPort:1433,
      localHost:'127.0.0.1',
      localPort:22
    };
```

But I believe it would be better suited if you just use the same port as your database one (`1433`). Keep in mind your MSSQL client will have to connect on port 22 and `localhost`. Any other connection to `localhost:22` will end up at the MSSQL database service.

Some explanation of the ports:

`port`: The port where the remote SSH server is running.

`localPort`: The local port that will forward the connection to the remote port.

`dstPort`: The remote port where the connection will end.

Alternatively, the same can be done with a SSH client on your OS:

```
ssh -L 22:localhost:1433 yourSSHhost
```

Which would let you connect on `localhost` port `22` to your MSSQL server.

**Update**

With this tunnel:

```
ssh -f -N -L 1433:my-db.1234566.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:1433 ec2-user@bastion.ec2.ip.here -v
```

You could do it like this with `tunnel-ssh` library:

Would be:

```
    var config = {
      username:"ec2-user",
      password:"yourpasswordhere",
      host:"bastion.ec2.ip.here",
      port:22,
      dstHost:"my-db.1234566.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
      dstPort:1433,
      localHost:"127.0.0.1",
      localPort:1433
    };
```

You do need to set up the `user` and `privateKey` (+ `passphrase` if you have one) or the `password` if not using SSH keys.